# Clojurescript - Email Attachment with JSPDF+Cordova?

Tags: cordova, clojurescript, jspdf

I'm attempting to send an email with a PDF attachment using the JSDPDF library from my clojurescript code which is being run as an IOS app using Cordova. In addition, I'm using the cordova-plugin-email-composer in order to open and populate the default email application on the mobile device. I'm testing this using an iPhone.

I've tried various times, but am not able to get the email to attach. Everything else though, (subject, to, body) all populate correctly.

Here's some of the things I've tried:

```
(let [doc (js/jsPDF.)]
    (.text doc "Hello world!", 10, 10)

 (.open (.-email (.-plugins js/cordova)) (clj->js {:body "test tst" :to (to-array ["test@test.com"]) :subject "Your Time Report" :attachments (to-array [(.output doc "datauristring")])}))

 (.open (.-email (.-plugins js/cordova)) (clj->js {:body "test tst" :to (to-array ["test@test.com"]) :subject "Your Time Report" :attachments (to-array [(.output doc "blob")])}))

 (.open (.-email (.-plugins js/cordova)) (clj->js {:body "test tst" :to (to-array ["test@test.com"]) :subject "Your Time Report"
      :attachments (to-array [  (str "data:application/pdf;base64," (js/btoa (.output doc)))  ])})))
```

All of these currently net similar results. In all cases, I'm seeing the attachments array generated correctly on the object being passed to open, but no attachment is added to the email.